# How many emails can be associated with one Apple ID FaceTime account?

Tags: ipad, ipod-touch

How many different email addresses can be associated with one Apple ID FaceTime account?

Answer (score 1):

As long as those email addresses are not tied up with other Apple IDs, I don't think there is a particular limit.

My FaceTime has 4 emails associated with it - none of them are linked to other Apple IDs -  but when I tried associating a 5th email that was linked to another Apple ID, it would;t let me of course.

Comment: Thank you, Does adding additional emails change the primary apple id associated with the password?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Your primary email should remain untouched.